# How to override model form to create a user in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a new user from the `modelform` by calling the `CustomerUserManager` in `managers.py`

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            if args[0]["email"]:
                self.email= args[0]["email"]
                self.password= args[0]["password1"]
        except:
            pass

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = "__all__"

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        
        return CustomUserManager.create_user(self,email=self.email,password=self.password,name="hic")
```

The managers.py is

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, name,**extra_fields):
       ...
        user = self.model(email=email,name=name, stripe_customer_id=customer.id ,**extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Obviously the `self.model` does not exist, so how can I correctly create that user from the `modelform`? If I import the model, I get circular error import.

here is my `model.py`

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("first name"), max_length=50)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want a save function in your form, rather than in your view using the model's save() function after your form data has validated...

That said, if you do want a create_user function in your manager, you would call it like

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
get_user_model().objects.create_user(...)
```

This should ensure the model is present to be referred to.

Comment: this returns `'CustomUserForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'`

Comment: That usually means you have not used save(commit=False) first.